# Scrapy: get all tags following a certain <a> tag within a <td> tag

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I have the following page I need to scrape with Scrapy: http://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=B2M

My task is to get the summaries from the GeneCard, which, in HTML, look like this:

```
<td>
    <a name="summaries"></a>
    <br >
    <b>Entrez Gene summary for <a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/query.fcgi?db=gene&cmd=Retrieve&dopt=full_report&list_uids=567" title="See EntrezGene 
    entry for B2M" target="aaa" 
    onClick="doFocus('aaa')">B2M</a> Gene:</b><br >
    <dd> This gene encodes a serum protein found in association with the major histocompatibility complex (MHC) class I
        <br >
    <dd>heavy chain on the surface of nearly all nucleated cells. The protein has a predominantly beta-pleated sheet
        <br >
    <dd>structure that can form amyloid fibrils in some pathological conditions. A mutation in this gene has been shown<br ><dd>to result in hypercatabolic hypoproteinemia.(provided by RefSeq, Sep 2009) </dd><br ><b>GeneCards Summary for B2M Gene:</b><br ><dd> B2M (beta-2-microglobulin) is a protein-coding gene. Diseases associated with B2M include <i><a href="http://www.malacards.org/card/balkan_nephropathy" title="See balkan nephropathy at MalaCards" target="aaa" 
        onClick="doFocus('aaa')">balkan nephropathy</a></i>, and <i><a href="http://www.malacards.org/card/plasmacytoma" title="See plasmacytoma at MalaCards" target="aaa" 
        onClick="doFocus('aaa')">plasmacytoma</a></i>. GO annotations related to this gene include <i>identical protein binding</i>.</dd><br ><Font size=-1><b>UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot: </b></font><a href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P61769#section_comments" target="aaa" 
                onClick="doFocus('aaa')">B2MG_HUMAN, P61769</a></font><dd><b>Function</b>:  Component of the class I major histocompatibility complex (MHC). Involved in the presentation of peptide<br >
    <dd>antigens to the immune system</dd>
```

Now, I want scrapy to get the text from this. However, I can't figure out how to get Scrapy to select a `<td>` based on the fact that it has `<a name="summaries">` in it. Does Scrapy have an undocumented Selector feature which lets you select a tag based on the fact that it does (or doesn't) explicitly contain a specific child tag?

Comment: use xpath: something like `//td[//a[contains(@class, "summaries")]]`

Comment: Oddly, that gets everything I *don't* want it to... whereas using "//td[a[contains(@name,'summaries')]]" gets solely the a tag in the td I want. But, that's a first step I hadn't found before, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated:

You can use **xpath** started with `sel.xpath('.//a[@name="summaries"]')`... I haven't got scrapy on this mac, so I'm using **lxml**, and in fact, in **lxml** you can use **getparent()**, **iterslibings** ...etc. many ways indeed, here's one of the samples:

```
from lxml import html

s = '... your very long html page source ...'
tree = html.fromstring(s)

for a in tree.xpath('.//a[@name="summaries"]'):
    td = a.getparent() # getparent() which returns td
    # iterchildren() get all children nodes under td 
    for node in td.iterchildren():
        print node.text
```

Results:

```
None


None
Summaries
(According to 
None
None
Entrez Gene summary for 
None
 This gene encodes a serum protein found in association with the major histocompatibility complex (MHC) class I
```

---

Alternatively, use `itersiblings()` to grab all sibling nodes around `<a>`:

```
for a in tree.xpath('.//a[@name="summaries"]'):
    for node in t.itersiblings():
        print node.text
```

...

Or, if you're after ALL the text actually included in the parent `td`, you can just use xpath `//text()` to grab them all:

```
for a in tree.xpath('.//a[@name="summaries"]'):
    print a.xpath('./..//text()')
```

Very long results:

```
['\n\t', '\n', '\n', 'Jump to Section...', '\n', 'Aliases', '\n', 'Databases', '\n', 'Disorders / Diseases', '\n', 'Domains / Families', '\n', 'Drugs / Compounds', '\n', 'Expression', '\n', 'Function', '\n', 'Genomic Views', '\n', 'Intellectual Property', '\n', 'Localization', '\n', 'Orthologs', '\n', 'Paralogs', '\n', 'Pathways / Interactions', '\n', 'Products', '\n', 'Proteins', '\n', 'Publications', '\n', 'Search Box', '\n', 'Summaries', '\n', 'Transcripts', '\n', 'Variants', '\n', 'TOP', '\n', 'BOTTOM', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Summaries', 'for B2M gene', '(According to ', 'Entrez Gene', ',\n\t\t', 'GeneCards', ',\n\t\t', 'Tocris Bioscience', ',\n\t\t', "Wikipedia's", ' \n\t\t', 'Gene Wiki', ',\n\t\t', 'PharmGKB', ',', '\n\t\t', 'UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot', ',\n\t\tand/or \n\t\t', 'UniProtKB/TrEMBL', ')\n\t\t', 'About This Section', 'Try', 'GeneCards Plus']
['Entrez Gene summary for ', 'B2M', ' Gene:', ' This gene encodes a serum protein found in association with the major histocompatibility complex (MHC) class I', 'heavy chain on the surface of nearly all nucleated cells. The protein has a predominantly beta-pleated sheet', 'structure that can form amyloid fibrils in some pathological conditions. A mutation in this gene has been shown', 'to result in hypercatabolic hypoproteinemia.(provided by RefSeq, Sep 2009) ', 'GeneCards Summary for B2M Gene:', ' B2M (beta-2-microglobulin) is a protein-coding gene. Diseases associated with B2M include ', 'balkan nephropathy', ', and ', 'plasmacytoma', '. GO annotations related to this gene include ', 'identical protein binding', '.', 'UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot: ', 'B2MG_HUMAN, P61769', 'Function', ':  Component of the class I major histocompatibility complex (MHC). Involved in the presentation of peptide', 'antigens to the immune system', 'Gene Wiki entry for ', 'B2M', ' (Beta-2 microglobulin) Gene']
```